Query macro gives "error returned from database: (code: 1) near $1: syntax error" with sqlite
I'm trying to query a local sqlite database with sqlx but I keep getting a syntax error, even after trying every variation of parameterized queries (e.g., "$1", "?", and even "?1" as they have shown in their sqlite example at https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/e33e4510fcab184f6bb655be3ba811e7f8a5b63f/examples/sqlite/todos/src/main.rs).
I'm kinda lost at this point. Here's a snippet of code where Rust complains:
pub async fn insert_to_database<T: Request>(db_pool: &SqlitePool, request: T) -> Result<i64>
{
    let id = query("INSERT INTO $1 ($2) VALUES ($3)")
        .bind(T::ParentTable::TABLE_NAME)
        .bind(T::ParentTable::SELECT_ORDER[4..].to_string())
        .bind(request.body())
        .execute(db_pool)
        .await?
        .last_insert_rowid();

    Ok(id)
}

and it complains in every other query statement as well (insert, fetch, etc.). Request is a custom trait I've written, but I've confirmed that the values in the bind are correctly returning their intended values within the function. I would appreciate any help!

I don't think the table name can be a parameter.

I don't think you can use parameters (e.g. $1) for the table name…

Would it be somewhat bad practice if I use format! for the table name instead? Since it's  a static string that I set so there shouldn't be much risk of injection... I think

Using format! should be fine since you control the string. Even better would be if there was some kind of const string formatting library able to create &'static str from const values, but I don't know of one.
